# Port possible? (grim fandandroido)

Tags: android

The dream is to run Grim fandango on my android,
And i stumbled onto 'residual' (http://residual.sourceforge.net/ it's a c++ application) and someone who made it to run on his nokia n900 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO9a5nTMHYI).

So for the question, would this be possible for android? My initial thought was the support debian and ubuntu and my android is faster then the n900, why not?

So before i spend days/weeks learning and getting it to work on my android,
I thought it might be a good idea to ask people who actually know about these things if its even possible.
And maybe how much work it really would be, in my head it's currently only:

1. make allot of Android.mk's
2. try to compile and fix errors still it works.

Which (if i don't get to many errors) doesn't sound to hard.

Any thoughts are welcome,
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Great question, I'd love to have Grim Fandango on Android. On a side note, there's rumors about Lucas Arts going for a mobile remake of the game (pocketgamer).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your goal is totally feasible.

Residual seems to rely on standard C++ libraries, plus OpenGL and SDL. For the latter, there are actually several [SDL Android ports](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=libsdl+android&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=HXpDTf3HIoaShAfts62dAg) out there you can take advantage of.

Somebody familiar with Android and the NDK could probably get Residual to a somewhat playable state in a few days (a proper port would take much longer ofc). If you're new to the platform however, you should be prepared to spend several weeks learning the basics of native application development in Android before tackling the project.